# SharePoint List contains filed "Title" by default, have to change that field as dropdown using "jQuery" or "JavaScript"

Tags: sharepoint-2010

SharePoint List contains filed "Title" by default, have to change that field as dropdown using "jQuery" or "JavaScript" in content editor web part and also that drop down should contain the values like "Regression Testing", "Unit testing" and also this drop down should allow the user to enter the data in drop down. Could you please help on this I tried but I am unable to change the text field as drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The Title field is special. You can rename the Title field on a list, but you can't change its data type because it is too fundamental to SharePoint. You also cannot delete the Title field.

Instead, consider hiding the Title field, then adding a different choice field for your testing drop-down.

To hide a field, first go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings, and enable management of content types. Then go to List Settings, click the name of your content type ("Item" by default), then click on the Title column and mark it as Hidden (instead of Optional or Required).

You certainly can customize the New and Edit forms of your list with JavaScript to hide the Title field and instead show a custom dropdown that populates the Title field onchange, but that seems unnecessarily complicated for what you're trying to accomplish.